# Are these tasks still possible after instagrams 10/15/19 api changes?

Tags: instagram, analytics, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api, social-likes

Are these tasks still possible after instagrams 10/15/19 api changes?

1. Connecting our platform to the users Instagram account.
2. User posting a picture through our platform to Instagram.
3. Pulling the number of likes on that picture on our platform.

Thank you in advance for your answers. I appreciate the help big time.

Comment: these answers should be available on instagram's API docs.

Comment: I agree. I was hoping someone here would know since I'm not a developer but I have an app in development. We've had some back and forth with our dev team saying we should be fine and now they said we may have some difficulty. When I read the api documents my head spins because this is all new jargon to me.

Comment: you should be putting the pressure on your dev team to research these issues for you. Sadly I don't do any Instagram work but your dev team should be able to read their docs and be able to figure that out or be able to contact the instagram development team.